Windsurf. Ошибка
подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался подтверждаю команду кнопкой accept, пишет запускается крутится и ничего не происходит. Хотя до этого работало, никаких изменений в системе не делал. Раньше подтверждались все команды, теперь работает через одну. Команда как пример.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
